# database not working on android c# unity

Tags: c#, database, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a game in Unity using C# and did quite well while using database online or in desktop, but can't get it to work on android. I used Sqlite4Unity3D plugins and code, and looked online but can't understand why isn't working.

It does work on PC, but on Android it simply doesn't do what is supposed to.

I have this code:

```
     using UnityEngine; 
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using Mono.Data.Sqlite;

using System.IO;
```

public class BancoDeDados : MonoBehaviour
{

```
private string conn;
private IDbConnection dbconn;
private IDbCommand dbcmd = null;
private IDataReader reader;


private string CADASTRARFASE = "UPDATE Fases SET Fase";
private string selectTodosFases = "SELECT * FROM Fases";
private string inserirFase = "INSERT  INTO Fases (Fase1) VALUES ('false');";
// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    conecta ();
    dbcmd.CommandText = selectTodosFases;
    IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (!reader.Read()) {
        reader.Close ();
        reader = null;
        dbcmd.CommandText = inserirFase;
        IDataReader reader2 = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
    }

    desconecta ();
}


public int checaIsTrue() {
    conecta (); 
    dbcmd.CommandText = selectTodosFases;
    IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (!reader.Read()) {
        return 1;
        desconecta ();
    } else {
        desconecta ();
        return 0;
    }


}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{

}



public void cadastraFase(string i) {
    conecta ();
    string cad = CADASTRARFASE + i + "='true';";
    dbcmd.CommandText = cad;
    reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();

    desconecta ();
}

private void desconecta() {

    dbcmd.Dispose();
    dbcmd = null;
    dbconn.Close();
    dbconn = null;
}


private void conecta() {
    conn = "URI=file:" + Application.dataPath + "/projetomuseu.s3db"; //Path to database.

    dbconn = (IDbConnection) new SqliteConnection(conn);
    dbconn.Open(); //Open connection to the database.

    dbcmd = dbconn.CreateCommand();
    string sqlQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [Fases] (\n[Fase1] BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'false' NULL,\n[Fase2] BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'false' NULL,\n[Fase3] BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'false' NULL,\n[Fase4] BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'false' NULL,\n[Fase5] BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'false' NULL,\n[Fase6] BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'false' NULL,\n[Fase7] BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'false' NULL,\n[Fase8] BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'false' NULL,\n[Fase9] BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'false' NULL\n)";
    dbcmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
    reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();


    reader.Close();
    reader = null;

    sqlQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [Colecionaveis] (\n[Co1] BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'false' NULL,\n[Co2] BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'false' NULL,\n[Co3] BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'false' NULL,\n[Co4] BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'false' NULL,\n[Co5] BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'false' NULL,\n[Co6] BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'false' NULL,\n[Co7] BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'false' NULL,\n[Co8] BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'false' NULL,\n[Co9] BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'false' NULL,\n[Co10] BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'false' NULL,\n[Co11] BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'false' NULL,\n[Co12] BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'false' NULL,\n[Co13] BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'false' NULL,\n[Co14] BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'false' NULL,\n[Co15] BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'false' NULL,\n[Co16] BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'false' NULL,\n[Co17] BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'false' NULL,\n[Co18] BOOLEAN DEFAULT 'false' NULL\n)";
    dbcmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
    reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();

    reader.Close();
    reader = null;



    sqlQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [Biografias] (\n[Bio1] BOOLEAN DEFAULT '''false''' NULL,\n[Bio2] BOOLEAN DEFAULT '''false''' NULL,\n[Bio3] BOOLEAN DEFAULT '''false''' NULL,\n[Bio4] BOOLEAN DEFAULT '''false''' NULL,\n[Bio5] BOOLEAN DEFAULT '''false''' NULL,\n[Bio6] BOOLEAN DEFAULT '''false''' NULL,\n[Bio7] BOOLEAN DEFAULT '''false''' NULL,\n[Bio8] BOOLEAN DEFAULT '''false''' NULL,\n[Bio9] BOOLEAN DEFAULT '''false''' NULL,\n[Bio10] BOOLEAN DEFAULT '''false''' NULL,\n[Bio11] BOOLEAN DEFAULT '''false''' NULL,\n[Bio12] BOOLEAN DEFAULT '''false''' NULL,\n[Bio13] BOOLEAN DEFAULT '''false''' NULL,\n[Bio14] BOOLEAN DEFAULT '''false''' NULL,\n[Bio15] BOOLEAN DEFAULT '''false''' NULL,\n[Bio16] BOOLEAN DEFAULT '''false''' NULL,\n[Bio17] BOOLEAN DEFAULT '''false''' NULL,\n[Bio18] BOOLEAN DEFAULT '''false''' NULL\n)";
    dbcmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
    reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
    reader.Close();
    reader = null;

}
```

It work just fine when I run it in the editor, but doesn't when I export it on my Android.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I can only assume that the path to your database is incorrect. 

You could try to display the conn variable into a textfield on your screen and then check that path on your device.

Comment: it was that! i checked online and they told to use a different path if you're running outside the editor! thanks

Comment: Any time! Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use Application.persistentDataPath insted of Application.dataPath and it worked!